# for + array + args

Tags: directory, array, for

I have problem with my for cycle, this is what I want:

```
for arg
do
array[index]=(`find $arg -type l -maxdepth $depth -printf "%p\n" `)
 index++
done
fi
```

`arg` - positional arguments, only directories

This cycle go through the arguments and finds symbolic links and I want them to be stored in an array. If I run script with only one directory it works okay, but when I enter two or more directories it does not work. Any help ?

I want to work it like this, for example:

There are two arguments, each one is directory.

Cycle first set arg to first directory and then array is filled with symbolic links for example it will find 2 symbolic links so array[0] array[1] will be that links and then it should continue with second arg and there are for example 3 symbolic links and it should set them to array[2] array[3] array[4]

Comment: what shell? Did you miss a `$` before the `(`, does the for need an `in …`,

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking `ksh93` or `bash` (and GNU `find`), there's no multidimentional arrays (or arrays of arrays), you could do though:

```
index=0 IFS=$'\n'
set -f
for arg do
  eval "array_$index"'=($(find "$arg" -type l -maxdepth "$depth" -print))'
  ((index++))
done
```

To have different arrays called `array_0`, `array_1`...

(the above assumes filenames don't contain newline characters).

If you want all the links merged into a single array, then:

```
IFS=$'\n'
set -f
array=($(find "$@" -type l -maxdepth "$depth" -print))
```

should be enough.

Using arrays or loops in shells are often a sign that you're not getting at the problem the right way.

For instance, if you want to find the *deepest* symlink (as your comment suggests), you'd do something like:

```
find "$@" -type l -print | awk -F/ '
   NF > n {deepest = $0; n=NF}
   END {print "Deepest:", deepest}'
```

`awk` is going to be a lot more efficient than the shell to process text and work with arrays. It is designed for that. Shells are not (and `bash` of all shells is one of the most inefficient ones at it). Shells are good at running commands (like `awk` or `find`), that's what they're designed for.

Comment: do you know how to count every / in every index of array ? i want to find out which symbolic link have the longest path so i want to make something like i will count every / in array[0] then array[1]
and store it int new array for exm maxarray and in max array i will find maximum and then again i will go through array and count / and when count of / and max are equal i will echo that link

Comment: and how to rewrite your scrip with awk that output will be like output in this command find -type l -printf "%p -> %l\n" and i want to count "/" only in %l can you help me ? because i have never used awk